# Why isnt my RichTextBox not changing foreground color databinding

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

So I am currently trying to print out the messages from a process to a richtextbox, and everything is working great besides that I want it to show the error messages in red text and the normal messages in green.

For some reason it's all green and I would assume it's becasue I am binding the foreground and not Appending to the RTB but I am not sure.

How do I properly make it to where the error messages turns red and the normal messages turn green.

MainWindow.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static Server server = new Server();
        private readonly Thread ConsoleThread = new Thread(() => { server.Start("Start.bat"); });

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = server;
        }

        private void ButtonStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ConsoleThread.Start();
        }

        private void tbConsole_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
            => tbConsole.ScrollToEnd();
    }
```

Server.cs

```
class Server : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private Process pServer = new Process();

        private Brush color;

        public Brush MessageColor
        {
            get { return color; }
            set
            {
                color = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MessageColor");
            }
        }

        private string outStream;
        public string OutputStream
        {
            get { return outStream; }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    outStream += value + Environment.NewLine;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OutputStream");
                }
            }
        }


        public void Start(string Path)
        {

            pServer.StartInfo.FileName = Path;
            pServer.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pServer.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pServer.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;


            pServer.OutputDataReceived += OKDataReceived;
            pServer.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataReceived;


            pServer.Start();

            pServer.BeginOutputReadLine();
            pServer.BeginErrorReadLine();
        }

        private void OKDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageColor = Brushes.Green;
            OutputStream = e.Data;
        }

        private void ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageColor = Brushes.Red;
            OutputStream = e.Data;
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handle = PropertyChanged;
            if (handle != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
 <Grid>
        <Button Click="ButtonStart" Content="Start" Margin="325,63,353,319"/>
        <xctk:RichTextBox FontSize="5" Name="tbConsole" Margin="143,149,164,81" BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="10" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="{Binding Path=OutputStream, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="{Binding Path=MessageColor}" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think you're right: the `Foreground` property refers to all text in the `RichTextBox`, not to individual items.

I can suggest a solution to your question, but bear with me...

**Collect the messages individually**

When I say "message", what I mean is anything being passed to `OKDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived`.

There's an issue in your architecture in that you don't distinguish between "good" messages and "bad" messages from your process. `OutputStream` contains both, and when `MessageColor` changes it will change for all previous messages, not just the latest one.

I would suggest changing creating a `Message` class with the message text and a flag for whether it's a "good" message or a "bad" message. When you get new data from the process you create the `Message` and set the flag for "good" or "bad" accordingly.

Then replace `OutputStream` with a property of type `ObservableCollection<Message>`. After creating a new `Message` from the process you can add it to this `ObservableCollection<Message>`. This is the property that will ultimately get bound to your view. Note that when a new item is added to an `ObservableCollection` it will automatically refresh the binding.

Now, I haven't forgotten your original question as to how to display text on the view with different colours. I can give you a suggestion for this, but it depends on having an `ObservableCollection<Message>` in the model.

**Convert the messages to a FlowDocument**

Bind the `ObservableCollection<Message>` to the `RichTextBox` control but use an `IValueConverter` to convert all the `Messages` into a [`FlowDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument(v=vs.110).aspx). Each Message would be converted into a [`Paragraph`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph(v=vs.110).aspx) with a [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run(v=vs.110).aspx) which would contain the text. You would then set the `Foreground` property on the Paragraph to the correct colour for the flag in the `Message`. You would also need to bind the property to the `RichTextBox.Document` property. The MSDN article for [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox)&rd=true%23Examples) has a nice little example that I think you'll be able to figure out from there.

The main disadvantage to this approach is that whenever the process emits a new message, it would require the entire `ObservableCollection` to be converted to a `FlowDocument` again, not just the new item. But I think the performance impact from that would be minimal.

I think this would be the best approach. At the end you would have a view model with distinguishable messages, a converter that can be modified as needed, and only a few changes to the view itself.

Comment: I like that! I've played around with ObservableCollections before but wow, this will be a challange! I'll start working on right away and hopefully get it to work, I really liked the idea of creating a class that destinguishes the "good" from the "bad" messages.